# Ho do I place a div over top of a jquery gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been struggling with this for a few days and I'm now going to ask for help.
I'm creating a site that uses an open source full screen jquery based gallery called "galleria".

What I would like to do, is place a div with my nav menu on top of this gallery close to the   bottom of the page. The jquery gallery I'm using is just like the one found here;

http://galleria.aino.se/media/galleria/src/themes/fullscreen/fullscreen-demo.html

At the bottom is a small tab that one can click to display the image thumbnails.
I would like to place my div basically between the thumbnails and main image.
I've tried nesting my nav in my galleria div, positioning the galleria div absolutely and the   nav div relative and giving the galleria a z-index of -1, and also positioning the   galleria div relatively and the nav div absolutely and give the nav a z-index of 20.

I can't even seem to get my nav to show on top of the galleria div as it is always hidden underneath.

I'm still sort of new to this so, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The main image has a z-index of 10000